# Disable night mode for Piker

Tags: android, react-native, react-native-picker

I have an app , but night mode changes colors (white to black) in Piker from @react-native-picker/picker. I tried

```
<item name="android:forceDarkAllowed">false</item>
```

and

```
AppCompatDelegate.setDefaultNightMode(AppCompatDelegate.MODE_NIGHT_NO);
```

but it's not helped
How to force disable night mode for Piker ?

```
compileSdkVersion = 31
kotlinVersion = "1.6.20"
buildToolsVersion = "30.0.2"
"react-native": "0.68.0",
```

Answer (score 0):

This issue was related to the dark theme, from dark mode. The solution was to change in styles.xml:

https://github.com/react-native-picker/picker/issues/274

Answer (score 0):

This issue was related to the dark theme, from dark mode. The solution was to change in styles.xml:

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.DayNight.NoActionBar">
```

to

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
```